# Quick question about antisymmetric relationship.

Tags: relations

Here we go,
It is a really yes or no question.
If aRb is a|b then is this antisymmetric? a, b belongs to integers including 0*

Comment: I think yes it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it? Consider if $a \mid b$ and $b \mid a$. Can this happen for integers $a,b$ and them not be equal?

**Hint:** Consider $b=-a$.

**Solution:**

> Consider $a=1, b=-1$. Each divide the other but $a \ne b$. Therefore no antisymmetry.

Comment: I love the way of spoiler. But I get this by the hint and thanks. It's my bad that I stuck with such an easy question sorry.